# TAMANHO DE UM DATAFRAME

Tags: r, dataframe

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de saber qual a capacidade de tamanho de um data frame no R, tenho um caso  em que utilizado o pacote Sidrar do R conexão direta ao API do IBGE para captura de dados, tive o seguinte retorno:

```
All others arguments are desconsidered when 'api' is informed
Error in get_sidra(api = "/t/3939/p/1990-2017/v/all/n6/all/c79/2670") : 
  Quantidade de valores solicitados: 155876 excedeu o limite: 100000
>
```

Gostaria de saber se é um caso específico do pacote, ou se o tamanho de um data frame é de capacidade de 100000 linhas.

Comment: A capacidade de um dataframe é dada pela memória disponível. Esse erro pode ser devido a um limite do IBGE, muitas vezes acontece haver limites de pedidos de dados impostos pelas instituições.

Answer (score 3):

Não é um problema do pacote nem do R e, sim, da API Sidra.

Por exemplo, `d <- data.frame(A = runif(10000000))` é armazenado sem problemas.

[No site de ajuda da API](http://api.sidra.ibge.gov.br/home/ajuda), temos:

> **Limite de consulta aos dados**
>
> A consulta aos dados está limitada a 10.000 valores. Para saber quantos valores a sua consulta irá gerar, multiplique a quantidade de seleções feitas em cada uma das dimensões